# What is an electrical node?

Tags: voltage, power, current, nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

In English books, the node in electricity connects two elements while in French books the node is defined as the junction of three conductors. Which of the two definitions is more accurate?

Comment: My view is a junction of *two or more* elements. A wire-OR connfiguration might easily have 16 (or more) elements tied together.

Answer (score 3):

In electrical systems, a voltage node is a region where the voltage is the same throughout the region. A current node, is also a voltage node, where current branches combine or merge.

There can be several current nodes within a single voltage node.

Comment: So in the literature we have defined two types of nodes: voltage node and current node

Comment: Another question a branch is defined between two voltage node ?

Comment: I've heard voltage nodes used in casual talk about electronics but I've never heard anyone who wasn't writing a simulator talk about a current node.